# How to build filtered construction predicates in CGAL?

Tags: c++, floating-point, geometry, computational-geometry, cgal

I want to use CGAL's exact predicates inexact constructions kernel, but I would like to use exact arithmetic on few selected `Plane_3` constructions where intermediate computation of the plane coefficients may overflow/underflow.

In other words, I am trying to build a custom `Construct_plane_3` functor that, which may use exact arithmetic internally but rounds the result back to an inexact kernel plane coordinates.

In code:

```
 #include <CGAL/Filtered_kernel.h>
 #include <CGAL/Filtered_construction.h>

 typedef CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<float>> Kernel;
 typedef CGAL::Filtered_construction<...> Custom_construct_plane_3;

 // standard inexact construction
 K::Point_3 point(0, 0, 0);
 K::Plane_3 inexact_plane(point, point, point);

 // custom inexact construction with filtered exact
 // arithmetic for the intermediate computations
 Custom_construct_plane_3 custom_construct_plane_3_object;
 K::Plane_3 exact_plane = custom_construct_plane_3_object(point, point, point);
```

The template parameters  `...` is the missing piece of the puzzle that I can't figure out.

Comment: Have an exact Kernel2, convert the points to Kernel2::Point_3, construct the plane, convert it to Kernel::Plane_3. (see Cartesian_converter)

Comment: Filtered_construction is not documented, probably that should be a hint not to use it. But if you really want to, I guess you should have FK=Simple_cartesian<Interval_nt_advanced>, EK=Simple_cartesian<Gmpq>, FC=FK::Construct_plane_3, EC=EK::Construct_plane_3, C2E=Cartesian_converter<K,EK>, etc.

Comment: With regards to your first suggestion, is the construction filtered in that case? ie will it be fast exactly representable by underlying float type?

Comment: No, it isn't filtered. You might be interested in the lazy kernel.